# select max() and other fields

Tags: mysql

We have a table:

```
create table ducks (id int(8) primary key not null auto_increment,
                    name varchar(255),
                    car varchar(255), 
                    money int(8)
                   );
insert into ducks set name='donald', car='none', money=10;
insert into ducks set name='scrudge', car='bip', money=10000;
insert into ducks set name='mac', car='bip', money=1000;
insert into ducks set name='joe', car='boo', money=2000000;
```

So analizing this I found that we got slow queries on the following request:

```
select name,money from ducks where car='bip' order by money DESC LIMIT 1;
```

because table is big and sorting just to get one record is very long

I found that the following works faster:

```
select distinct name,money from ducks where money=(select max(money) from ducks where car='bip')  LIMIT 1;
```

but still not sure, because it is subselects.

what is common way to solve this ?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2b7ed/6

**update** it turned that in reality we have a task to not searching same car but search richest duck which have less than $100000

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2b7ed/21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wise to be wary of subqueries; especially in MySQL.

The following query uses a self-exclusion join, and in basic testing performs the best of the three. Your first solution is fine, but as you say slow. It is also not ANSI-compliant, but that may not matter to you. Your second solution is also fine, but MySQL does not handle subqueries as well as might be hoped; at least traditionally.

```
select 
  d.name, d.money
from 
  ducks d
  left join ducks d2 
  on d2.car = d.car 
  and d2.money > d.money
where 
  d.car = 'bip'
  and d2.id is null
```

Implemented here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27711/20

---

Edit: The goalposts somehow moved. Darn those goalposts. This is the self-exclusion join solution for the new problem: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7146d/13

```
select 
  d.name, d.money 
from 
  ducks d
  left join ducks d2 
  on d2.money > d.money
  and d2.money < 100000
where 
  d.money < 100000 
  and d2.id is null;
```

Comment: oh, sorry seems i messed with question (narrowed it to much)... in real task we doing something like  `and money<100000` , not sure if it possible to implement your aproach, can you help little further ? [like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2b7ed/21)

Comment: Solution to revised problem: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7146d/13 I have also edited my answer to include this other solution. Thank you.

Comment: so generally i should apply to all fields on d2 same comparsions as d1 has and compare d1,d2 value to get min/max ?

Comment: Generally, yes, you're right. But as you can see in the first solution, if the WHERE condition does NOT apply to `money` then we only need to specify it once and then self-join on `car`.